# Преобразование JSON в XML

Tags: php, json, xml, преобразование, конвертация

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.WQeGF4jyjcc, он неплохо справляется с конвертацией, но как это сделать с помощью PHP?

Comment: Парсите JSON в объект и затем объект в XML

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php, http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php